# Can Intelli IDEA view original code like eclipse's way

Tags: eclipse, intellij-idea

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kblP3.png)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y28gO.png)

In eclipse , you can view origin code pressing <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>; but in IDEA, I must press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + MOUSE DOWN to another page to look it. Can IDEA like Eclipse?

Comment: Yes, you can set the whole thing as Eclipse. `Settings->keymap`. Play with that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In IntelliJ, it called Quick Definition. It is bound to `Alt+Space` or `Cmd+Y` in my environment, however, it would be different depending on keymap.

Open your `Preferences dialog > Keymap` and find `quick definition` in the right pane of the dialog. You will be able to see the key binding for that.